# jQuery tabs are not created for partial view, when re-posted with Ajax.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have this tiny problem.

I have DIV with id="Contacts", javascript renders some partial VIEW and loads it into that DIV container.

VIEW is basically html page that has uses jQuery tabs plugin to display content with tabs.

the very last row in the VIEW is:

```
$(function () { 
   $("#contacts").tabs({ selected: 1 }); 
});
```

When it is loaded first time, everything is perfect.

The VIEW has an Ajax.ActionLink, that reloads that partial view back to it's container DIV.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("RELOAD", 
"Contacts", 
null, 
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "contacts", LoadingElementId = "loading" })
```

Everything works except, TABS are not created anymore. Just bulleted links.
The script at the end of the VIEW is executing, but doesn't create tabs.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: after the actionlink gets executed, you need to fire javascript again.

Comment: @Ajax.ActionLink("RELOAD", 
"Contacts", 
null, 
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "contacts", LoadingElementId = "loading",OnSuccess = "$("#contacts").tabs({ selected: 1 });" })

Comment: Thank you very much, Parminder, I'll give it a try. Just wondering why the javascript on the PartialView is not firing...

Comment: if you post the whole code set, i can better help you.